# Admob ads not working in Unity 5.3.5p7 personal

Tags: unity-game-engine, admob

I'm using this unity plugin but I'm not able to receive ads. When I build the code for iOS and run it on (using Xcode) iPhone below will happen. I call the below function

```
private static InterstitialAd interstitial;
public void RequestInterstitial()
{
     string adUnitId = "inter_admob_id";
     // Create an interstitial.
     interstitial = new InterstitialAd(adUnitId);
     // Load an interstitial ad.
     interstitial.LoadAd(createAdRequest());
}
```

On following line in the code:

```
interstitial = new InterstitialAd(adUnitId);
```

I receive this error in xcode logs:

> NotSupportedException: To marshal a managed method, please add an
>   attribute named 'MonoPInvokeCallback' to the method definition.
>       at GoogleMobileAds.iOS.Externs.GADUSetInterstitialCallbacks (IntPtr interstitial,
>   GoogleMobileAds.iOS.GADUInterstitialDidReceiveAdCallback
>   adReceivedCallback,
>   GoogleMobileAds.iOS.GADUInterstitialDidFailToReceiveAdWithErrorCallback
>   adFailedCallback,
>   GoogleMobileAds.iOS.GADUInterstitialWillPresentScreenCallback
>   willPresentCallback,
>   GoogleMobileAds.iOS.GADUInterstitialDidDismissScreenCallback
>   didDismissCallback,
>   GoogleMobileAds.iOS.GADUInterstitialWillLeaveApplicationCallback
>   willLeaveCallback) [0x00000] in :0 
>       at GoogleMobileAds.Api.InterstitialAd..ctor (System.String adUnitId) [0x00000] in :0

Below is my "Player Setting" screenshot
[Player Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6PNAF.png)
Please help me out

Answer (score 0):

You just have to do as instructed in Log message:

> please add an attribute named 'MonoPInvokeCallback' to the method
>   definition. at
>   GoogleMobileAds.iOS.Externs.GADUSetInterstitialCallbacks (IntPtr
>   interstitial, GoogleMobileAds.iOS.GADUInterstitialDidReceiveAdCallback
>   adReceivedCallback,
>   GoogleMobileAds.iOS.GADUInterstitialDidFailToReceiveAdWithErrorCallback
>   adFailedCallback,
>   GoogleMobileAds.iOS.GADUInterstitialWillPresentScreenCallback
>   willPresentCallback,
>   GoogleMobileAds.iOS.GADUInterstitialDidDismissScreenCallback
>   didDismissCallback,
>   GoogleMobileAds.iOS.GADUInterstitialWillLeaveApplicationCallback
>   willLeaveCallback) [0x00000] in :0 at
>   GoogleMobileAds.Api.InterstitialAd..ctor (System.String adUnitId)
>   [0x00000] in :0

Add `[MonoPInvokeCallbac(type)]` attributes before callbacks in IOSInterstitialClient.cs :

```
#region Banner callback methods

[MonoPInvokeCallback(typeof(GADUInterstitialDidReceiveAdCallback))]
private static void InterstitialDidReceiveAdCallback(IntPtr interstitialClient)
{
    IntPtrToInterstitialClient(interstitialClient).listener.FireAdLoaded();
}

[MonoPInvokeCallback(typeof(GADUInterstitialDidFailToReceiveAdWithErrorCallback))]
private static void InterstitialDidFailToReceiveAdWithErrorCallback(
        IntPtr interstitialClient, string error)
{
    IntPtrToInterstitialClient(interstitialClient).listener.FireAdFailedToLoad(error);
}

[MonoPInvokeCallback(typeof(GADUInterstitialWillPresentScreenCallback))]
private static void InterstitialWillPresentScreenCallback(IntPtr interstitialClient)
{
    IntPtrToInterstitialClient(interstitialClient).listener.FireAdOpened();
}

[MonoPInvokeCallback(typeof(GADUInterstitialWillDismissScreenCallback))]
private static void InterstitialWillDismissScreenCallback(IntPtr interstitialClient)
{
    IntPtrToInterstitialClient(interstitialClient).listener.FireAdClosing();
}

[MonoPInvokeCallback(typeof(GADUInterstitialDidDismissScreenCallback))]
private static void InterstitialDidDismissScreenCallback(IntPtr interstitialClient)
{
    IntPtrToInterstitialClient(interstitialClient).listener.FireAdClosed();
}

[MonoPInvokeCallback(typeof(GADUInterstitialWillLeaveApplicationCallback))]
private static void InterstitialWillLeaveApplicationCallback(IntPtr interstitialClient)
{
    IntPtrToInterstitialClient(interstitialClient).listener.FireAdLeftApplication();
}

private static IOSInterstitialClient IntPtrToInterstitialClient(IntPtr interstitialClient)
{
    GCHandle handle = (GCHandle) interstitialClient;
    return handle.Target as IOSInterstitialClient;
}

#endregion
```

Comment: I already selected IL2CPP as scripting backend. Player Setting shared in my question please review that.

Comment: @ZeeshanArif which version of Admob are you using?

Comment: "Admob Unity Plugin 3.0.5" from the link https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-unity/releases

and Admob for IOS version 7.9.0

Comment: @ZeeshanArif check the answer now